# Disable Url Bar from Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to disable the address bar on the browser. All opinions suggest that this is not possible, especially in modern browsers. I was about to believe this and move on until I found out that Pluralsight did it. [Here](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/mvc4-building) is a link. Just expand one of the sections and click on one of the videos. No matter which browser you use, it will work (a new window will open with a disabled address bar). I had a close look at the page source but that revealed nothing. I can assess the following:

- They are not using any plugin (no Silverlight or Flash) because it worked just fine on [Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/microsoft-edge) which does not support plugins.
- It's not a regular popup window, because I got no warnings or popup block messages with any browser whatsoever.

Can anybody suggest how that can be done?

Comment: What you are referring to is a modal window...

Comment: It's not a regular modal window though. If you mean a modal Window like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp), then no it's not like it. It's a standalone window. You can close the original website and the window would still be open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually just a plain ol' [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) being used.

In the source of the page you linked to is:

```
function openPlayerFromTranscript(e, t, r) {
    var n = "width=1354,height=836,status=0,titlebar=0,scrollbars=0,menubar=0,toolbar=0,location=0,resizable=1";
    window.open(getPlayerUrlForTranscript(e, t, r), "psplayer", n)
}
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you.

Comment: @yazanpro Sure thing!

Answer (score -1):

```
window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=0', 'menubar=0', 'scrollbars=0', 'status=0', 'titlebar=0', 'toolbar=0');
```

`'location=0'` will work only for Opera browser